# Using Android Webview with a Squidman Proxy and locally hosted website

Tags: android, cordova, webview, proxy

I am developing a mobile website which is running on Apache (XAMPP) and is mapping to https://dev.myapp.com using the HOSTS file and vhosts config. The development site also uses self-signed certificates

I can access the app fine via my browser however now I am trying to develop a WebView App using Cordova, the cordova webview works fine when loading content from our production server (https://myapp.com) but just shows a white page when I try to load content from my development server on an android device.

I use squidman on my mac to create a proxy for my phone to connect to the development server and again this works fine on a normal browser. And works ok if i run the webview on ios, I am therefore assuming this is specific to the android webview...

Has anyone come across this issue, am i missing some configuration details?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, not all applications use the proxy, but the browser definitely does.

The best solution I found so far is to install [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) on a rooted device and force all apps to use the proxy